# Running Makefile but the last file is skipped - R

Tags: r, plot, makefile, ggplot2

Maybe I am doing something very stupid here, but I really can't spot my mistake. Here is the Makefile:

```
R_OPTS=--no-save --no-restore --no-init-file --no-site-file

data/clean_data.RData: R/0_clean.R data/raw_data.dta
    cd R;Rscript 0_clean.R $(R_OPTS)

fig/ttest_result.pdf: R/1_1_ttest_result.R data/clean_data.RData   
    cd R;Rscript 1_1_ttest_result.R $(R_OPTS)
```

With only `raw_data.dta`, if I run `make`, the `clean_data.RData` is created but `ttest_result.pdf` is not. However, when I run `make fig/ttest_result.pdf` explicitly, the file is created. I'm really lost about why?

Extra info: `1_1_ttest_result.R` is creating `ttest_result.pdf` with ggplot2 using `ggsave()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default when you run a make file with no target is just to build the first target. In this case, that's only "data/clean_data.RDat" so that's the only file that will get created. That's why you often see makefiles like

```
R_OPTS=--no-save --no-restore --no-init-file --no-site-file

all: data/clean_data.RData fig/ttest_result.pdf

data/clean_data.RData: R/0_clean.R data/raw_data.dta
    cd R;Rscript 0_clean.R $(R_OPTS)

fig/ttest_result.pdf: R/1_1_ttest_result.R data/clean_data.RData   
    cd R;Rscript 1_1_ttest_result.R $(R_OPTS)
```

so the first target lists everything you want to build by default.

Comment: I knew it must be something straightforward  :( thanks!